# How do I best handle conversion into template type from const char *

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

I have a template function, within which I need to convert a const char * to my template value.
I know for a fact that this const char * was originally read from a ascii text file. My current code looks like this:

```
    template <typename T>
    bool Get(T &value, std::string const &query, T const &default)
    {
        const char* result = DataHandler.GetValue(query);
        if (result != NULL)
        {
            value = static_cast<T>(result); //Here is the issue
            return true;
        }
        value = default
        return false;
    }
```

Using this with an int as example i get the error

> error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'int'

Is there a way I can convert the char* to my type T seamlessly, I could not find an answer for this on SO.

In the worst case I can make a case for the 10 types I expect and give an error if not one of these, but I would rather not do it that way if possible.

Comment: Add a convert function that is specialised for each type you support.

Comment: Converting a string has many interpretations, for example one could convert "0xFF" to 255, or not support hex. You'll need to decide which you support and add those in (there are lovely standard functions like atoi that can help)

Comment: What data is in this string?  ASCII representation of a typed number?  A bitwise copy of the original value?  Are you converting the text `Stairway to Heaven` to an MP3?  There's no one way to convert "ASCII" to an arbitrary object type.  This question lacks clarity.

Comment: The general way to handle this is to templatize the conversion and add that as a template argument, defaulting that argument to something sensible, and customizing if you want to do something esoteric.  Also, your function is returning `bool`, so it is clearer to return `true` or `false`, not `1` and `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can convert the char* to my type T seamlessly,

No.

There is no way to make conversion from string to a type automatically work with all types. Such conversion has to be implemented for each class. Typically, it is done by implementing the stream extraction operator `>>` for `std::istream`. The built in types such as `int` and some standard types such as `std::string` already have such operator. Then you can do for example:

```
std::istringstream istream(result);
int i;
istream >> i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you are asking for, using the answer given by @eerorika, here is a generic way to do the conversion:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct DefaultConverter
{
    static T Convert(const char *result)
    {
       std::istringstream istream(result);
       T i;
       istream >> i;        
       return i;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Converter = DefaultConverter<T>>
bool Get(T &value, std::string const &query, T const &defaultVal)
{
    const char* result = "100";
    value = Converter::Convert(result); 
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int test = 10;
    Get(test, "abc123", test);
    std::cout << test;
}
```

The code referring to the `DataHandler` function is not important to illustrate what the above does.

Basically, the `Get` function takes an additional argument, namely a conversion template that has an available `Convert` function that can be called by `Get`.  Note that the default converter simply uses the code as illustrated in the previous answer given by @eerorika.

This gives you the flexibility of providing your own converter that has a `Convert` function that can do anything customized.

For example:

```
struct SomeMPEGObject
{
    SomeMPEGObject() {}
    SomeMPEGObject(const char *) {}
};

struct MPEGConverter
{
    static SomeMPEGObject Convert(const char *result)
    {
       return SomeMPEGObject(result);
    }
};
//...

SomeMPEGObject mpeg;
Get<SomeMPEGObject, MPEGConverter>(mpeg, "12345", mpeg);
```

This will work without changing any code in the `Get` function.

Comment: This looks really good, is there somewhere I can look up which types already have the >> operator implemented, and which types I would have to overload/ provide my own converter?

Comment: Let the compiler do the work.  If the type has an `operator >>` ok, if not, then the compiler will give an error.

Comment: The idea is that the `Get` function should be documented that the default will call `>>` on the type, and any customization (or if the type doesn't have `>>` overloaded), then provide the custom conversion type.  This is no different than, say, `std::sort` requiring your type to have `<` available by default, or if not, a lambda or function object / function describing the sort criteria.  Another variation is to create two `Get` functions, one that works automatically for `>>`, and another that requires the conversion function to be specified.